# Spring Boot Test MockMvc perform post - Not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testing, post, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a Integration test using the Spring Boot but the post request is not working. The method *saveClientePessoaFisica* is never called and do not return any kind of error! I just tried to make other tests using a get method and it works properly.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class ClienteControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;


    @Test
    public void nao_deve_permitir_salvar_cliente_pf_com_nome_cpf_duplicado() throws Exception {

        this.mvc.perform(post("/api/cliente/pessoafisica/post")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content("teste")
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/cliente")
public class ClienteController {

    @Autowired
    private PessoaFisicaService pessoaFisicaService;


    @PostMapping(path = "/pessoafisica/post", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> saveClientePessoaFisica(@RequestBody PessoaFisica pessoaFisica) throws Exception {

        this.pessoaFisicaService.save(pessoaFisica);

        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your content "teste" is no valid JSON. When I am using your code, I'm getting a JsonParseException complaining about that (By the way, there is a parenthese missing after content("teste") ). Also helpful is using andDo(print()) which will give you the request and response in more detail:

```
@Test
public void nao_deve_permitir_salvar_cliente_pf_com_nome_cpf_duplicado() throws Exception {

    this.mvc.perform(post("/api/cliente/pessoafisica/post")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content("teste"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Some things to look for :

- Enable logging in your mockmvc
- Enable your mockmvc properly
- When using spring security, initialise it in mockmvc
- When using spring security / CSRF / HTTP POST , pass a csrf in your mockmvc
- Enable debug logging

Like this :

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

Working test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MockMvcTest {

    @Autowired
    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).apply(springSecurity()).build();

    }

    @Test
    public void adminCanCreateOrganization() throws Exception {

        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/organizations")
                .with(user("admin1").roles("ADMIN"))
                .with(csrf())
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(organizationPayload("org1"))
                .accept(APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This log tip was very usefull!

Comment: The autowired mvcMock is replaced in the init method. Also if you need to use a simple user and role better annotate the test function with    `@WithMockUser(username = "admin1", roles = "ADMIN")`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this debug tip! Very useful and practical